# Inserting different Object at runtime, Generics JAVA

Tags: java, generics

I was learning about generics in JAVA while I came across this point:

> Generic type checks are done only at compile time. Its a bad idea to modify code to insert other instances at runtime.

I do not know enough Java to tweak code to do this at runtime yet. Reflection maybe? Hence, I was not able to try it out to see what happens. So, my question, what is it that would happen if the above is done? Why and how is it bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would get a `ClassCastException`. Consider this example (of what not to do):

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List asRaw = intList; // Bad! Your compiler will complain / warn. Don't ignore it.
asRaw.add("not a number");
Integer myInt = intList.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

This is because generics are erased at compile time -- that is, internally, the `ArrayList` only knows it has a bunch of `Object`s. (Google for Java erasure for lots more info on this.) The compile-time generics turn into runtime casts, which are guaranteed to work if your generics usage is safe (no raw types, no arrays of parameterized types, no reflection to put in bad values). If your usage is not safe (as in the example above), the casts can fail, causing a `ClassCastException`. This can actually happen somewhat far from the area where the bad value was put in -- or even far from where it was taken out -- so it can be hard to track down.

Answer (score 4):

No need for reflection:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();        
        Object tmp = strings;

        // Unsafe cast
        List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>) tmp;
        integers.add(10);

        String x = strings.get(0); // Bang! (ClassCastException)
    }
}
```

That *does* give a warning, but it's still valid code. There may be ways of achieving similar things without a warning, if you're subtle... just don't do it.

The answer to "what is it that would happen" is shown above: you'd get an exception *but probably later than you might expect*. You'll get the exception when you try to *use* the rogue element, as that's when there'll be a cast.